# How do I proceed with the following message from the terminal? See details

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I sometimes encounter this message when I input some commands in the terminal.

```
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 14: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated. please move it to /home/ethiojob/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf manually
```

What's the message about, and how do I fix it so that it doesn't appear again?

I'm not sure if I should simply cut out the 14th line and paste it in the second file, or cut-paste the whole file together.

Comment: This came up googling, but I've never had the issue: http://www.itworld.com/article/2985788/linux/how-to-fix-fontconfig-warning-errors-in-linux.html

Comment: warnings are benign. take notice of it. you could post a bug report on it. But you can also ignore it since it will fix itself when an update is made for it.

Comment: you can also apply this (adapted to your line number): http://askubuntu.com/questions/206271/how-can-i-bypass-this-fontconfig-warning-to-edit-grub-successfully